# Google Analytics - spurious page views?

Tags: google-analytics

Every day I get views of the same two pages in the same minute from the same user (using Chrome 65.0.3325.181 on Windows 10).
Interesting though the pages are, obviously (?), I don't believe these are real, intentional, views, especially as one of them is our main catalogue and there are never any events signalled for this session, which is untypical for that page.
I think all this must be happening automatically, perhaps because tab content is re-activating when the browser is restarting?
Does anyone know how such spurious page views can be filtered out of GA? I only want to count views that someone is actually looking at!
Many thanks
Mandy

Additional information as requested by Michele to whom I am very grateful.

I've prepared a spreadsheet with more info re all this user's visits, it's here: https://www.iperimeter.co.uk/Resources/SpuriousPageViews.xlsx.

Notes:

1) There look to be 2 puzzles here: firstly the user's strange activity, looking at only these pages over and over again, and secondly the lack of signalled GA events when there must have been /some/ for him/her to have got to the point they did (see comments in spreadsheet).
I suppose it is just possible the activity is 'normal', so that the lack of signalled events is the only real mystery.

2) Website is http://www.notamos.co.uk.

3) User has same GA cookie, operating system/version, and browser/version throughout.

4) My GA setup dates from early Dec 2017, so, given that there is no 'original' source for the direct referrals listed, I can only imagine that the user favourited my site pre December.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the option 'Exclude all hits from known bots and spider' in the view setting?

Comment: What is the source of these hits (direct, referral, ...)? Have you more info about these hits?

Comment: Just edited the original post to provide more information.

Comment: Think I must have accidentally deleted my answer to Michele's original question - yes I have excluded bot/spider hits in GA.